# How can I stop JavaScript from modifying the clipboard?

Tags: browser, javascript, copy-paste, clipboard

More and more I find that when I copy text from a news site, the site adds in its own advertising/footnote link to my clipboard, so that when I paste, the copied text is appended with something like:

> [Text I copied]  FOR MORE, GO READ AT http://www.example.com/link/to/story

I admire the technical abilities that made this possible, but I would like to stop it on my browser.  I looked through about:config for "clipboard" and "copy," but the only setting I found was autocopy on highlight.

Is there a good way to stop this so that when I copy I get only the text I highlighted, relying only on Firefox's built-in copy feature and not triggering anybody's JavaScript or other site customizations?  I don't like sites telling my browser how to work.

As an example, copy one of the [fun "facts" here](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2007/10/28/fun-chuck-norris-vs-linus-torvalds/) - when you paste, you'll have the following text appended:

> Read more: http://www.linuxscrew.com/2007/10/28/fun-chuck-norris-vs-linus-torvalds/#ixzz1mUKtACkt

They aren't just hijacking the control-C keystroke, I get it when I select "copy" from the right click menu, as well.

I would like my browser to completely ignore this trick.

I replicated this on Firefox, IE, and Google Chrome.

Comment: I think that IE doesn’t do that.

Comment: Are you pressing [Ctrl]+[C] to copy? The system's copy hotkey may be getting intercepted by JavaScript and setting `Selecton`+`Junk` to the Clipboard. A more likely case is that there is hidden text (via CSS) that is being included in your selections. If you include a link to such an article, we can examine it and find a workaround or solution to this horrible practice.

Comment: Further reading: http://daringfireball.net/2010/05/tynt_copy_paste_jerks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this JavaScript code is being served by a "service" called tynt.com.  Redirecting tcr.tynt.com to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file solved the problem for me.  From what I read elsewhere, there may be multiple servers that need to be blocked.  Adblock list subscriptions may also take care of the problem, and you may be able to set up a filter in your ad blocking software to correct it.

What I would really like would be a flag in about:config to remove permission for JavaScript to modify the clipboard.

Answer (score 9):

To disable this behavior in Firefox:

1. In the URL bar, type: `about:config`
2. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. In the search box, type: `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled`
4. Double-click it to toggle its value to **false**.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me in Firefox 68.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe only happens when I select one of the advertisement links that is underlined in green:

[image: Advertisement Link]

So when you copy that, nobody is hi-jacking your clipboard. You're copying the hyperlink from the website.

To prevent these links from being inserted into the website, look into advertisement blocking solutions for your browser.

Comment: No, I am afraid it happens on every line.  However, I've discovered it may be blocked by some ad blocking lists.

Comment: I tried it with Firefox, Chrome and IE. They all showed the same behavior. I assume **where** the links are placed and how they look might even differ between instances.

Comment: Did you read the answer I gave about tynt?  Apparently tynt is mercifully blocked on your machine or network.  It was for a coworker of mine, too.  The behavior I was getting was totally different from what you describe.  I was getting text inserted, the words "Read more:", not just a hyperlink.